# RxJava Schedulers- Thread Behavior and Starvation?

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a double-take  with the `observeOn()` and `subscribeOn()` with RxJava. I understand that they do not parallelize emissions on a single stream. In other words, a single stream of emissions will only be put on one thread correct? My test below seemed to indicate this. My understanding also is you have to `flatMap()` a scheduler, as in `.flatMap(v -> Observable.just(v).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))`, to parallelize emissions on a single stream.

Also if that is the case then could thread starvation happen with the schedulers? If my computation scheduler has 5 threads, but I have more than 5 long-running asynchronous streams being processed is there a possibility starvation could occur? Or is this unlikely just because of RxJava's nature?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Observable<String> airports = Observable.just("ABQ", "HOU", 
            "PHX", "DAL", "DFW", "AUS","SAN","LAX","JFK");


        airports.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(Test::stall)
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub1 " + s +
                " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        airports.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(Test::stall)
        .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Sub2 " + s +
                " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        sleep();
    }

    private static String stall(String str) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }

    private static void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `flatMap`, it is possible one async source is overwhelmed by others and it can't make progress on its own source. In practice, however, I haven't seen this happen due to OS and JVM hiccups that give enough breathing room and because of backpressure and arbitration in `flatMap` itself. If you are worried about this overwhelming, you can use the `maxConcurrent` parameter with a `flatMap` overload and limit the number of concurrent subscriptions.

RxJava is mostly written in a non-blocking fashion so when sources need to be merged or combined, they don't really wait for each other.

Computation scheduler is a pool of single-threaded executors and are assigned in round-robin fashion to callers. I don't know about the fairness of the standard executors.

Comment: Yeah I guessed the nonblocking nature of RxJava must have something to do with mitigating the possibility of an issue. I never had problems with thread resources but was speculating if it was possible. Good to know, thanks!